# Undefined is not a function in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm building an class to render maps using the Google Maps API.

This is my class

```
function Map() {
}

Map.prototype.map = null;
Map.prototype.map_options = null;
Map.prototype.div_map = null;
Map.prototype.directions_service = null;
Map.prototype.center = null;
Map.prototype.points = null;

Map.prototype.start = function() {

    this.map_options = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: this.center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.div_map), this.map_options);

    this.directions_service = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    this.directions_service.setOptions({
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeWeight: 2,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeColor: "blue"
        }
    });

    this.map.setMap(this.directions_service);
};
```

When I use this class, a received an error, in this line:

```
this.map.setMap(this.directions_service);
```

The error is: `Uncaught Typeerror: undefined is not a function`

But, I test the `this.map` variable with `typeof()`, and returns `'object'`.

The `this.div_map` is set normally, also, the initial map in rendered.

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object map has no method 'setMap'. But DirectionRenderer has. You have to change that line to

```
this.directions_service.setMap(this.map)
```